# forwardRef with custom component and custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref, react-custom-hooks

Edit: Small changes for readability.

I'm new to react and I may be in at the deep end here but I'll go ahead anyway..

I have a Login component in which I want to give the users feedback when the input elements lose focus and/or when the user clicks submit.

I am aware that I achieve a similar bahavior with `useState` but for the sake of education I'm trying with `useRef`.

I'm getting a TypeError for undefined reading of `inputRef` in `LoginForm.js`. So `inputRef` is not assigned a value when `validateInput` is called. Can anyone help me make sense of why that is and whether there is a solution to it?

LoginForm.js:

```
import useInput from '../../hooks/use-input';
import Input from '../../UI/Input/Input';

 const LoginForm = () => {
  const { inputRef, isValid } = useInput(value =>
    value.includes('@')
  );

  return <Input ref={inputRef} />;
};
```

use-input.js (custom hook):

```
const useInput = validateInput => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const isValid = validateInput(inputRef.current.value);
  return {
    inputRef,
    isValid,
  };
};
```

Input.js (custom element component):

```
const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} {...props.input}></input>;
});
```

Comment: What does useInputRef do?

Comment: It is a custom hook (also included in the second code section of OP).  It returns two things:
    inputRef = useRef()
    isValid = a boolean. the result of calling the argument function validateInput(inputRef.current.value)

Comment: Sorry @mahan the naming was confusing. It is fixed now (useInputRef is now useInput)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that I'm seeing is that in the `Input` component, you're using `props.input`, why?

```
const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} {...props}></input>;
});
```

You want exactly the props that you're sending to be assigned to the component.

Next up, you're doing `value.includes('@')`, but are you sure that `value` is not `undefined`?

```
const { inputRef, isValid } = useInput(value =>
    value && value.includes('@')
  );
```

This would eliminate the possibility of that error.

---

Solving the issue with the `inputRef is undefined` is not hard to fix.

Afterward, you're going to face another issue. The fact that you're using `useRef` (uncontrolled) will not cause a rerender, such that, if you update the input content, the `isValid` won't update its value.

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. (React Docs)

This is a personal note, but I find uncontrolled components in general hard to maintain/scale/..., and also refs are not usually meant to do this kind of stuff. (yes, yes you have `react-form-hook` which provides a way of creating forms with uncontrolled components, and yes, it's performant).

In the meantime, while I'm looking into this a little more, I can provide you a solution using `useState`.

```
const useInput = (validationRule, initialValue='') => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

  const onChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value)

  const isValid = validationRule && validationRule(value)

  return {
    inputProps: {
      value,
      onChange
    },
    isValid
  }
}
```

So, right here we're having a function that has 2 parameters, `validationRule` and `initialValue`(which is optional and will default to text if nothing is provided).

We're doing the basic `value / onChange` stuff, and then we're returning those 2 as `inputProps`. Besides, we're just calling the `validationRule` (beforehand, we check that it exists and it's sent as parameter).

How to use:

```
export default function SomeForm() {
  const { inputProps, isValid } = useInput((value) => value.includes('@'));
  
  return <Input {...inputProps}/>;
}
```

---

The following part is something that **I strongly discourage**.
This is bad but currently, the only way of seeing it implemented with refs is using an `useReducer` that would force an update `onChange`.

Eg:

```
const useInput = (validationRule) => {
  const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer((p) => !p, true);
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const onChange = () => forceUpdate();

  const isValid = validationRule && validationRule(inputRef.current?.value);

  return {
    inputRef,
    isValid,
    onChange
  };
};
```

Then, used as:

```
export default function SomeForm() {
  const { inputRef, onChange, isValid } = useInput((value) =>
    value && value.includes("@")
  );
  console.log(isValid);

  return <Input ref={inputRef} onChange={onChange} />;
}
```

Comment: Ah no, that's a typo. Corrected it now. Sorry about that!

The issue is as described: inpuRef is undefined when passed to validateInput() in use-input.js

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius for the elaborate answer.

The truthy check on value solved my issue. 

isValid is now updating on lost focus and submission, which is exactly what I was going for

The useState example you give is the same I'm using for my Signup component. As mentioned I wanted to implement this logic  with useref for educational purposes. I take note that it may not be best practice to use useRef for this use case.

Thanks again.